# How can I configure Lion to use PHP mail() locally?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, email

I'm doing web development with PHP on my mac and need to be able to use the mail command locally (on localhost). What do I have to configure to get the PHP mail() command working?

PS: On Windows I used [hmail](http://www.hmailserver.com/) for this.

---

I mean how to connect PHP with mail server on my mac, i noticed when i type mail on terminal, it seems mac already come with Mail Server.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with it you may be able to use the mail server included in OSX. Can you give some details about intended use?

Comment: Im going to use that for my localhost only. Im php webdeveloper. so i need mail server to handle PHP mail() :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://blogs.bigfish.tv/adam/2009/12/03/setup-a-testing-mail-server-using-php-on-mac-os-x/) works for me at OS X Snow Leopard:

- When an email is sent using PHP's mail() function, the email is piped through to the smtp_catcher.php script.
- The smtp_catcher.php script saves the email into a local folder as a .emlx file.
- The email is opened through Apple Mail and displayed on the screen (woo!).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you will need to install a PHP server on your machine like apache (http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi) or maybe wamp (windows only)(http://www.wampserver.com/en/).

Unlike HTML, JAVASCRIPT, CSS etc. PHP is a server side programming language (aka scripting language), meaning it compiles on the server, not the browser, and that you need to run a server to compile it.

Once you have the server running, make a .PHP file and put it in the 'site' folder, from there it will run :D

Comment: i already install PHP (MAMP). Please see my question, i update it to make it more clear.